# JavaFX Unrecognized option: --module-path

Tags: javafx

I am created loginApplication on JavaFX. In the IntelliJ IDE this application works fine. Problems began then I created executable .jar file and I tried run on command prompt, but getting error. I tried with all java versions from 11 to 14, JavaFX from 11 to 15, but every time same error.

The issue below :

```
> C:\Users\>java -version 
> java version "1.8.0_251" Java(TM) SE RuntimeEnvironment (build 1.8.0_251-b08) Java 
> HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
> 
> C:\Users\>javac -version javac 12
> javac 12

> C:\Users\>echo %PATH_TO_FX% 
> C:\ProgramFiles\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
> 
> C:\Users\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12

> C:\Users\Desktop>java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules
> javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar LoginAplicationFX.jar 
> Unrecognized option: --module-path Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
> Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Any ideas how it can be solved? - So far no luck.

Comment: Your `java -version` is showing 1.8.0_251. The `--module-path` and other module-related arguments were added in Java 9. Check your environment variables, particularly `Path`. Make sure nothing is pointing to Java 8 if you don't want to use Java 8.

Comment: Thank you for help. For me suited: I deleted variable path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"  and worked like charm. :)

Comment: @davids1985 It didn't work for me. Any ideas?